# How to get JSON response only from an ob-restclient block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, restclient

I'm trying to construct an Org-based pipeline for some DevOps activities. Part of this requires making REST API calls and proceeding based on the results of those calls. I'm using `ob-restclient` for making actual requests. One example would be:

```
#+name: applications
#+begin_src restclient :output value raw
  GET :host/rest/deploy/application
  Authorization: Basic :auth
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json
#+end_src
```

`:host` and `:auth` are variables that I define elsewhere. Now, this works fine, except the `RESULTS` section looks like this:

```
#+RESULTS: applications
#+BEGIN_SRC js
[
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
]

// <some response headers>
#+END_SRC
```

I want to be able to use the named result (`applications`) as input variable to another code block, but the problem is, it's not a pure JSON string, but also contains the JS codeblock markers and the response headers. Any idea how I could get *only* the JSON part without parsing this string output? I suspect this might be configurable on `restclient`'s side, but I was unable to find a solution.

Comment: There is no org-babel header named `:output` AFAICT. An individual engine might define it but I don't see such in `ob-restclient.el`. Try `:results value`.

Comment: Tried that as well. I think this is just something that's `restclient` specific. I bypassed the problem by using a function to post-process the result (found one [here](https://justinbarclay.me/posts/literate_programming_against_rest_apis/#more-helper-functions)).

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a long time since this was asked, but in the current version of `ob-restclient` (`20220819.2228`), I am able to show only results by using the `:jq` option:

```
#+begin_src restclient :results pure :jq .
  GET :host/rest/deploy/application
  Authorization: Basic :auth
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept: application/json
  Content-Type: application/json
#+end_src
```